# Why can't I specify which Excel rows are used in X and Y axis in line graph?

Tags: excel, graph

I've got a very simple Excel spreadsheet showing the number of major volcanic eruptions per century (see screen snapshot).  I want to graph this with a simple line graph, with the century being the X axis, the number of eruptions being the Y axis.

No matter what I do, Excel insists on making the century the Y axis and the eruption count the X axis.  Yes, I have Googled this.  Accepted solutions that do not work involve swapping the rows and columns (disaster!)  I've also tried physically re-ordering the columns so that either the century or the eruption count comes first.  Still not luck.

Surely, it cannot be this hard.  What am I missing?  TIA.

[image]

In the above graph, the century is incorrectly being graphed along the Y axis, with values represented by the blue line.  Eruption count is along the X axis and looks flat as we're only dealing with values between 0 and 3.  I want to reverse the axis, with centuries running along X and eruptions on Y

Comment: Right-Click on any Excel chart(a little away from the plot itself) and get familiar with the Select Data dialogue box. It allows you to allocate Ranges, Captions etc to a graph. It's a dialog box that's central to your Graphing constructs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have a single data point `EruptionCount`. You want to have the `Century` data as your `Horizontal (Category) Axis Label`

See the image.

[image]

Comment: Perfect explanation Hoejanson.  My mistake was thinking I needed to include two columns in my data selection and let Excel sort it out.  It makes sense now.  I have one data point to plot; I just needed to do that and then configure the Axis to use my Centuries column.  Great answer!